# C# how to write a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I am trying to follow this tutorial on how to bind an array to a grid-view:
[Binding Arrays to GridView in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Binding-Arrays-to-GridView-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

It is easy enough to follow, but my array structure looks different that the one in the example. I would like to find out how to write an array that looks like this:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "aldo",
      "email": "aldo@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "matias",
      "email": "matias@email.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you,
Erasmo

Comment: are you looking to find the class structure? how to display it? can you show what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used code from the tutorial you mentioned and modified it in order to fit your requirements:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridMultiD" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial"
    Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 
    HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green" AllowPaging ="true"  
    PageSize = "10" Caption = "Multi-Dimensional Array" >
   <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px"
     DataField = "Name" HeaderText = "Name" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px"
     DataField = "Email" HeaderText = "Email" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

```
//Multi-Dimensional Array
string[,] arrMultiD = {
                    { "aldo", "aldo@email.com" },
                    { "matias", "matias@email.com"}
                 };
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add("Email", Type.GetType("System.String"));

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add();
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Name"] = arrMultiD[i, 0];
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Email"] = arrMultiD[i, 1];

}
GridMultiD.DataSource = dt;
GridMultiD.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. I am working on implementing it, I am not very experinced so it takes me way longer than you to follow and understand what I need to do. I will update this question soon after I am done, or if I have a question.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to say is, this not a multidimensional array. It's an array of `User` objects. In C# you could implement it like this.

```
public class User
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public string Email {get; set;}
}

List<User> users = new List<User>
{
    new User { Name = "aldo", Email ="aldo@email.com"},       
    new User { Name = "matias", Email ="matias@email.com"}
}
```

This would generate the JSON you've shown when serialized.

One slight thing to note is that C# uses Pascal-casing (**N**ame,**E**mail) whereas JavaScript and your JSON use Camel-casing (**n**ame, **e**mail).

Some JSON serializers (such the one for .NET Core WebAPI) automatically make this conversion, but other do not, so you may have to use an inappropriate convention in one language or the other.